# Why is CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin preventing my main js file from being minified?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, minify, mini-css-extract-plugin

I am using webpack's `CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin` ([docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin/)). I initially configured it as recommended on the documentation

```js
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      // For webpack@5 you can use the `...` syntax to extend existing minimizers (i.e. `terser-webpack-plugin`), uncomment the next line
      // `...`,
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
  },
```

But it seems that doing so prevents my `main.js` file from being minified too. I decided to change it and place it under the `plugins` tag, simply removing the optimization one completely like this:

```js
    plugins: [
        //other plugins
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    ],
```

And this way it seems to work, both the .css and .js files are being minified. I didn't find any reference to this under the docs provided above, so I would like to know, **why is this happening?** Why is it not working when using the documented set up?

For reference, please find my full *working* webpack configuration file below (*note that I am passing the development or production mode through the --mode flag*):

```js
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/main.js'),
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            esModule: false,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            // 0 => no loaders (default);
                            // 1 => postcss-loader;
                            // 2 => postcss-loader, sass-loader
                            importLoaders: 1
                        }
                    },
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html')
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
    devServer: {
        watchContentBase: true,
        open: true,
        writeToDisk: true,
    },
    // COMMENTED SINCE IT IS NOT WORKING CORRECTLY
    // optimization: {
    //     minimize: true,
    //     minimizer: [
    //       // For webpack@5 you can use the `...` syntax to extend existing minimizers (i.e. `terser-webpack-plugin`), uncomment the next line
    //       // `...`,
    //       new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    //     ],
    //   },
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Since version 4 webpack runs optimizations for you depending on the chosen mode, still all optimizations are available for manual configuration and overrides.](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/)

In particular, for `js` minification it uses [TerserWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/). When the optimization is overridden then the defaults of webpack do not take effect, using only the provided ones. In this case it only ran through the Css plugin.

To fix this, webpack offers the possibility of keeping existing minimizers by using `'...'`, so it should look like this:

```js
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    // other config
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
          // For webpack@5 you can use the `...` syntax to extend existing minimizers
          '...',
          new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
        ],
      },
}
```

Webpack includes `webpack-terser-plugin` by default in order to minify the `.js` files too. The configuration above would be *similar* to the following one:

```js
// This serves just as an example, webpack provides more optimization steps when using '...'
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    // other config
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
          // For webpack@5 you can use the `...` syntax to extend existing minimizers (i.e. `terser-webpack-plugin`), uncomment the next line
          new TerserPlugin(),
          new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
        ],
      },
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this sounds redundant, but I'm new to webpack. So it's not necessary to include the css minimizer or terser plugins unless we'd like to manually configure?

Comment: @Nunchuk You can check everything explained thoroughly in this github repo: https://github.com/Aridez/vue-tailwind-webpack-boilerplate#setting-up-cssminimizerplugin To sum up, we only need to configure the CssMinimizerPlugin as an additional optimization step. By using the `'...'` syntax the rest of optimizations are set automatically for you, for this reason we want to make sure to uncomment the `'...'` part so the rest of the optimization steps provided by webpack are left as is.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks for clearing that up for me and the link. Appreciate it.